# How to determine solutions: $\;2^x=3^y=36^{-z}\; \implies \frac1x +\frac 1y +\frac 1{2z} = \quad ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$2^x=3^y=36^{-z}\;$$ then $$\frac1x +\frac 1y +\frac 1{2z}$$
>   is equal to 
>   a) $\;0$ 
>  b) $\;1$ 
> c) $\;-1$ 
>   d) ***none of theses***

**How to solve this problem
please explain it**

Comment: There are actually infinitely many solutions to the problem as given.  Are $x, y, z$ integers?

Comment: @anorton, yes they are

Comment: Are you sure they are integers? There is no integer solution to $2^x=3^y$ other than $x=y=0$ which would make your expression undefined.

Comment: @amWhy It should be $\frac{1}{2z}$ for a reasonable answer. I questioned that too.

Comment: @CalvinLin That's what I suspected, too. I took the liberty to edit. Dear user84888, please double-check the edit to ensure I have expressed what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

For your expression to be valid, we need to assume that $xyz \neq 0$.

**Hint:** Using the rules of logarithms, we know that

$$ x \ln 2 = y \ln 3 = (2z) (- \ln 6) $$

**Hint:** Write $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x$ and substitute into your expression.

> $$\frac{ 1}{x} \left( 1 + \frac{ \ln 3} { \ln 2}  - \frac{ \ln 6} { \ln 2} \right) = \quad ??$$

Comment: Hope you don't mind the teeny (non-substantive) edit! Nice answer, btw ;-)

Comment: @amWhy No worries. I'm often too lazy with \left. I just discovered >! to hide stuff, and I think i'd start to write my answers as hints with things hidden, more fun for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $2^x=3^y=36^{-z}=k\implies x=\frac{\ln k}{\ln 2},y=\frac{\ln k}{\ln 3}$ and $z=-\frac{\ln k}{\ln 36}$

Therefore, $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2z}=\frac{\ln 2}{\ln k}+\frac{\ln 3}{\ln k}-\frac{\ln 36}{2\ln k}=\frac{\ln4+\ln 9-\ln 36}{2\ln k}=\frac{\ln 36-\ln 36}{2\ln k}=0$$